# ASP.Net MVC - How to embed multiple video in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mp4

I'm trying to create a view that displays multiple training videos. While I did get the following code to work once, I now get only black video frames.

My VideoController:

```
public ActionResult GetVideo()
    {
        var videoPath =
           Request.MapPath("~/Content/videoFile/IQ3612 Benefits.mp4");
        FileStream fs =
           new FileStream(videoPath, FileMode.Open);
        return new FileStreamResult(fs, "video/mp4");
    }

    public ActionResult GetVideo2()
    {
        var videoPath2 =
           Request.MapPath("~/Content/videoFile/IQ3612 Technical.mp4");
        FileStream fs2 =
           new FileStream(videoPath2, FileMode.Open);
        return new FileStreamResult(fs2, "video/mp4");
    }
```

My View:

```
<body>
<h1>Training Video Index</h1>
<div> 
    <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" >
        <source src="@Url.Action("GetVideo","Video")" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
        <source src="@Url.Action("GetVideo2","Video")" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just simply link directly to the file? Perhaps you've simplified your code here for the sake of the question, but as it stands, all you're doing is just adding overhead to the request. That said, I don't think that's necessarily your problem here, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: From my understanding, a file steam must be used. 

`<div> 
        <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" >
            <source src="~/Content/videoFile/IQ3612 Benefits.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>`

 does not work.

Comment: Umm. No. Either way it's not "streaming" if that's what you think. I mean in one sense everything over HTTP "streams" because it's downloaded in packets. If the video meta is front-loaded, the browser can begin playing it before it's finished downloading, but it's not adaptive (streaming in the sense of Netflix or a YouTube video). I'm not sure what you mean by "does not work", but the only reason linking directly would not work, is if the path the file is wrong.

Comment: OK. Yes I was wrong about having to use a file stream. I have been trying to get two videos to be seen on the same view. So originally when I tired your suggestion it was with two videos in a single view and it wasn't working. When I only have one video in my view, than yes your way does work as well as the way I show above works (but your way is simpler).

Comment: Two videos shouldn't make a difference. Functionally, this is no different that referencing an image with and `img` tag. You can include as many `img` tags as you want and you can also include as many `video` tags as you want.

Comment: I have been trying to do this on my local computer, and maybe that is where my issue lies. I will try your suggestion on a web server and see if it then works for me.

Comment: Well your code specifies the display size so those black boxes could be just empty displays. Do you get sound with these "black bars"? If not it could be a file path issue, make sure your code can access the file, check what it sees/finds by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the MIME type for the .mp4 format is set correctly in your `web.config` file.

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I did not have this in my web.config. I did add it but my videos still do not work.

Comment: @Kram_Koorbse Please do check the rendered HTML to see if `@Url.Action("GetVideo","Video")` generates a valid path. It can be due to invalid or non-existent video URL - Your MapPath returns empty or null

Comment: I checked and can confirm that it does return a valid path. When I have only one video in my view, the video plays. When I try to have two videos in my view, like I show in my post, then neither video plays.

Answer (score 0):

> *While I did get the following code to work once, I now get only black
>   video frames*.

Could the file paths have changed since your last working test? You shouldn't have spaces in file names used as web URL's. For example : `IQ3612 Benefits.mp4` should be `IQ3612_Benefits.mp4` (here with underscore, or use dashes or fullstops).

The final URL : `~/Content/videoFile/IQ3612_Benefits.mp4`.

Also try as direct a path as possible. This means placing your file on a aserver and linking to them directly. Instead of tilde `~`, try HTTP version, `../Content/videoFile/IQ3612_Benefits.mp4`, but a direct link like `http://www.mysite/Content/videoFile/IQ3612_Benefits.mp4` would work best.